# pyspark find date with the highest amt.

Tags: date, timestamp, pyspark

I have the following df:

> time                loc      amt
>   2012-07-20 01:00:00 A        3300
>   2012-01-04 17:29:00 B        300
>   2012-07-20 01:00:00 A        200
>   2012-01-04 17:29:00 B        500
>   2012-01-04 17:29:00 C        333

I would like to output the date that had the highest amt.

output:
2012-07-20

How do I do this using pyspark?

Answer (score 0):

How about just collect the max value first and then filter?

```
max_amt = df.select(max(df.amt)).collect()[0][0]
df.filter(df.amt == lit(max_amt)).select(to_date('time')).show()
+------------+
|todate(time)|
+------------+
|  2012-07-20|
+------------+
```